# C# converting httpclient post into restsharp post without async method on autopilot

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, restsharp, autopilot

I have this piece of code that I'm trying to convert from async task [Http client post] into a rest sharp post method. Here is the working example of async task method that works with  httpclient:

```
 static async Task addEmailToListAsync(string ListName, string Email, string FirstName, string LastName)
    {
        try
        {
            var baseAddress = new Uri("https://api2.autopilothq.com/");

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
            {

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("autopilotapikey", "mykey");

                using (var content = new StringContent(""))
                {
                    using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("v1/list/" + ListName + "/contact/" + Email, content))
                    {
                        string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            await addEmailToListAsync(ListName, Email, FirstName, LastName);
        }


    }
```

This method works and autopilot returns a response in form of  " { } " - which indicated everything went well.

Now I'm trying to convert this using restsharp library and to achieve so that the method is not async task - but a simple void function:

```
 public static void addEmailToList(string ListName, string Email, string FirstName, string LastName)
        {

            var client = new RestClient("https://api2.autopilothq.com/");

            
            client.AddDefaultHeader("autopilotapikey", "mykey");

            var request = new RestRequest("v1/list",Method.POST);

            var jsonObj = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new 
            { 
                ListName = ListName,
                Contact = Email
            });

            request.AddParameter("application/json", jsonObj, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var res = client.Execute(request).Content;

            var test = "";
        }
```

This is the example that I tried when converting - but I keep getting message with restsharp that body data is invalid...

What am I doing wrong here? I'm pulling my hairs out and I can't figure it out..

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Why take it from async to non-async? That's the opposite direction we typically move in. Anyways, if you're getting an error, then you need to post the exact details in the question. What line does it happen on? What's the full message and stack trace? Are there any inner exceptions?

Comment: @mason there are no errors in the code- but rather in way of forming the request - its just that the in my method in 2nd example  I tried - I'm getting response from API that the request is not created well... Just can't grasp my head around it why..  I don't understand how should this type of post: httpClient.PostAsync("v1/list/" + ListName + "/contact/" + Email, content)) - look like in restsharp :/

Comment: In the first example it looks like you're making a POST request to a URL where the request body is empty and the URL contains your values.  In the second example it looks like you're making a POST request where the values are in the body instead of the URL.  Is that the intent?  If the server is replying that the request is invalid, maybe that intent was mistaken?

Comment: Well your HttpClient attempt posts to `https://api2.autopilothq.com/v1/list/<List Name>/contact/<Email>` while your RestSharp attempt posts to `https://api2.autopilothq.com/v1/list`. Do you see how those are different? Make them the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your working code sends the list name and email address in the URL, and an empty string as the request body.

Your non-working version sends the list name and email address as a JSON-serialized string in the body, and omits them from the URL.

The error message suggests that the API you're calling doesn't support the second method of passing data. Change your `RestSharp` code to match the URL and request body from your `HttpClient` code.

```cs
var request = new RestRequest("v1/list/" + ListName + "/contact/" + Email, Method.POST);
var res = client.Execute(request).Content;
```

Comment: OH yeah this is working, just a small change instead of last line - this made it work: 

          var res = client.Post(request).Content;